# How to retrieve data from MySql database based on a dropdown selection and button click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to retrieve some data from a MySql database on select change and button click. Data from the resulting row is supposed to be displayed in 2 text boxes in a hidden div, which is shown on button click.

**empstatus.php**

```
sql = "select * from mx_party_master";
$result = mysqli_query($db , $sql);
<body>

<?php myNav(); ?> <!-- A function to display a sidebar -->

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="jumbotron">
<form action="#" method="GET">

<!-- DROPDOWN LIST -->
<select class="form-control" name="selectemp" id="selectemp">
<option  value="">Select Party..</option>
<?php while($res= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
<option value="<?php $res['KUNNR']; ?>"><?php echo $res['KUNNR'].' 
'.$res['NAME1']; ?></option>
<?php }?>
</select>
<br>

<!-- BUTTON TO SHOW THE HIDDEN DIV AND RETRIEVE DATA FROM THE DATABASE -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark" name="subemp" 
id="subemp">Search</button>

<!-- DIVISION WITH INPUT FIELDS WHERE DATA IS TO BE DISPLAYED-->    
<div class="hiddendiv" style="display: none;">
<label for="open">Open Order: </label>
<input type="text"  class="form-control" name="open" id="open"/>
<br>
<label for="open">Open Delivery: </label>
<input type="text"  class="form-control" name="opendel" id="opendel" />
</div>

</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>

<!-- AJAX CODE -->

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    (function ($) {
        $('#selectemp').change(function () {
            $('#subemp').click(function(){
                $('.hiddendiv').toggle();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "empstatest.php",
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        data: $('#selectemp').serialize()
                    }).done(function (data) {
                        $('#open').val(data.ordblock); <!-- I'M SURE I'M DOING THIS WRONG -- >
                        $('#opendel').val(data.ordblock);
                    });
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
});
</script>
```

**empstatest.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-type: application/json');
$db = mysqli_connect("credentials");

$value =  $_POST['selectemp'];
$sql = "select ordblock, delblock from mx_crlimit where kunnr = '$value'";
$res = pg_query($db, $sql);
$is = '';
$data = pg_fetch_assoc($res);
$is = json_encode($data);
echo $is;
?>
```

I'm new to Jquery and there's probably something wrong the ajax code, especially where I'm trying to display the data in the input field. Kindly help me solve this issue.

Comment: You're not showing what is happening, how do we know what is wrong?  What result are you getting, where are you sending it?  But one thing that is not helping you is that your form method is set to GET and you are trying to access the POST, so I suspect your variables are unassigned

Comment: For a start, empstatest.php is not sending anything back to the AJAX call. Add a `echo $is;` after the last line

Comment: That's all the code I have written sir. I'm getting no output. Only the input fields are getting displayed.

Comment: add `echo $is;` in last line of empslatest.php

Comment: Where is your jQuery code and what output are you getting when you console log a response?

Comment: HI, I have added it. Still getting the same output.

Comment: What I want to do is, in empstatest.php, I'm getting 2 values from the database 'ordblock' and 'delblock'.  I want to display those data in 2 input fields in empstatus.php with id's '#open' and '#opendel'.

Comment: Hi, first of all did you included the jquery ajax library before using ajax ?<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @melonhusk - at the moment you aren't showing anywhere you are sending a request.  Please can you add your jquery code, as there is a gap between the form and empstatest.php - with your current code I can't see any way that you are accessing empstatest.php from your form.  Currently you have a php script trying to access the global $_POST variable, but we cannot ascertain what you are sending, or how you are dealing with the response.  Have you got some jQuery?

Comment: Hi James, this is that all the code I have written. I'm trying to access empstatest.php using what's written in $.ajax({ });

Comment: You need to have an Ajax call specifying the script you want to access and the function you want to update with the response.  Have a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Answer (score 1):

The problem, I believe, is that you have declared the `dataType` as `JSON` but you are, in fact, simply sending a string. If you omit the `dataType` entirely it works though processing the response ( and I don't use jQuery ) did not appear to work without further fudging - I added `JSON.parse( data )`

With luck the following demo will illustrate these changes and allow you to get your code working.

```
<?php
    /* this emulates the remote script ( empstatest.php ) */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        ob_clean();

        /* payload to emulate db call */
        $data=new stdClass;
        $data->ordblock=sprintf( 'ord-%d-%s', $_POST['selectemp'], uniqid() );  #randomness abounds!

        exit( json_encode( $data ) );
    }   
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
        <script>
            let url=location.href;/*empstatest.php*/

            $( document ).ready(function () {
                ( function($) {
                    $('#selectemp').change(function () {
                        $('#subemp').click(function(){
                            $('.hiddendiv').toggle();
                            $.ajax({
                                type:'POST',
                                url:url,
                                data: $('#selectemp').serialize(),
                                success:function( data ){
                                    let json=JSON.parse( data );
                                    $('#open').val( json.ordblock );
                                    $('#opendel').val( json.ordblock );
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
                })(jQuery);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select name='selectemp' id='selectemp'>
            <option selected hidden>Select
            <?php
                for( $i=1; $i<=20; $i++ )printf('<option value=%d>Option - %d',$i,$i);
            ?>
        </select>

        <button type='button' class='btn btn-lg btn-dark' id='subemp'>Search</button>

        <div class='hiddendiv' style='display: none;'>
            <label for='open'>Open Order: </label>
            <input type='text'  class='form-control' name='open' id='open'/>
            <br>
            <label for='open'>Open Delivery: </label>
            <input type='text'  class='form-control' name='opendel' id='opendel' />
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```